# Laravel: Validator to validate only fields which exist in the passed data?

Tags: validation, laravel

Currently the Validator will fail if I have a required rule for a key "name", but I haven't passed it in the data array. I want it not to fail in this case. I want to validate only the fields which exist in the data array. Is there a builtin way for that to happen, or I have to extend the Validator class?

Comment: Why do you use required on an input value that is NOT required?

Answer (score 42):

You can use the `sometimes` validation rule.

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list.

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
));
```

Be sure to run `composer update` since the sometimes shortcut is a Laravel 4.1.14 feature.

https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/422463139293057024

Comment: what about ['email' => 'email']; ? will this not work?

Comment: why on earth I would set "sometimes" and "required"? If it's "sometimes required", its nullable. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess you may want to check that if a field is present, has not to be empty, i think that case cover this

Comment: I really don't like the name of that rule.

Answer (score 21):

You can use nullable and it will pass if email is not present

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'nullable|email'
])
```

Also, you should remove `required` validation.

Comment: This isn't correct though. Let's say you have a login form and make the email field nullable, it will allow you to send the form without having entered an email address. With `sometimes` you can also use `required` at the same time which is probably needed for something like a login form.

Comment: Why on earth would you use sometimes and required? You have `required_with`, `required_if` for conditional cases.

Comment: I literally gave you an example. If somehow you're stubborn and still not convinced; the docs even tell you why to use it: "In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list".

Comment: I think this solution makes more sense because when you use sometimes, it will expect the field itself not present in the request, but in most cases, we do have the field present in the request but empty. Thanks again 

Comment: It took me a few reads to get this.  In case it helps someone else - the difference is in whether the field will always appear in the request but might have a null value, or might sometimes not appear in the request at all.  Use `nullable` for the former, and `sometimes` for the latter.  [There is a related note about this in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

Comment: I have a similar case when based on a selected value in my form, I have to display some specific fields and some of the fields are required only if they are present in the form data. 

Example: I have to choose the marketing campaign type (HTML, image, video) and for each type I have specific fields, like head & body for HTML, like file, height & width for the other two ... and so on.

Comment: It depends on how you are going to consume this endpoint. I tend to prefer sending null values instead of removing it from the body. In other cases, when you're not going to send the property, it's better to use "sometimes" instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel version less then 5.9

For anyone, having the validator object, using:

`Method ->validateFilled(string $attribute, mixed $value)`

may also help them to validate the given attribute is filled if it is present. May help someone in their respective case.

Source:- https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_validateFilled

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use this ?