# Unable to update users details without changing current profile picture at same time

Tags: laravel

Thank you so much to all! My final coding that fixed it in case ever helps anyone else.. Also this code can be cleaned up better but it worked.. ill clean it up now too though and update this again later.

```
    public function storePersonalInfo(Request $request, $lang){
        
        $this->validate($request, [
        'avatar' => 'sometimes|required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        'firstName'    =>  'sometimes|required',
        'lastName'  =>  'sometimes|required'
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();


        if ($file = $request->file('avatar')) {

        $filename = hash('sha1',$file->getClientOriginalName().'-'.time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;

        $filePath = 'users/'. Auth::user()->name.'/'.$filename;

        $image = Image::make($file);
        $image->fit(200, 200);

       
        if (Storage::put($filePath, (string) $image->encode())) {
            
        $user->avatar = Storage::url($filePath);
        }

        $user->first_name = $request->firstName;
        $user->last_name = $request->lastName;

        $user->save();

        flash(__('Profile Updated'), 'success');
        return back();
    }
    else
    {
        $user->first_name = $request->firstName;
        $user->last_name = $request->lastName;

        $user->save();

        flash(__('Profile Updated'), 'success');
            return back();
    }
}
```

///
ORIGINAL QUESTION ///

Users have a bio profile in their account to update any change of details and they cant update their name for example without having to attach a new profile pic upload for the name save to be accepted.. the code is below, can someone please advise on how i can have users update just name details without needing the profile at the same time too.. I mean there are cases when users may just want to updated their profile pic or just their name, surely is doesn't have to be a full completion every time..

Sorry to ask but really stuck on this.. this issue has probably been asked before but i am needed code specific assistance as i cant see exactly what I've done wrong and I been trying for a few days now.. Laravel isn't my expertise at all sorry! I have attached the profile controller code below:

```
    public function storePersonalInfo(Request $request, $lang){
        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'avatar' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
            'firstName'    =>  'required',
            'lastName'  =>  'required'
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();


        $file = $request->file('avatar');

        $filename = hash('sha1',$file->getClientOriginalName().'-'.time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;

        $filePath = 'users/'. Auth::user()->name.'/'.$filename;

        $image = Image::make($file);
        $image->fit(200, 200);

        

        if (Storage::put($filePath, (string) $image->encode())) {
            
            $user->avatar = Storage::url($filePath);
        
        }else{
            return back();
        }

        $user->first_name = $request->firstName;
        $user->last_name = $request->lastName;


        $user->save();

        flash(__('Profile info updated with success '), 'success');
        return back();
    }
```

tried various if else statements and couldn't figure it out unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The very first thing in your method is the validation, which says all 3 fields are required.  If you don't want to require all 3 fields, there's your problem.  To only validate something *if* it was submitted, you can use the `sometimes` rule, there are many examples here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/21070281/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58952137/6089612,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70115818/6089612, ...).  [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present) are also clear and good.  You don't require first/last, remove those rules completely.

Comment: You'll also need to update the rest of your method, which handles the image, to only run if there is an image present, since now it is possible that there won't be.  Eg something like `if $request->file('avatar') { ... image handling code ... }`.

Comment: (Don't Panic) Thank you so much - brain was burnt out !! feel free to check us out UNVS .com

Answer (score 0):

at the moment the validation you have require all the three fields to be present, so if one or more are not present it fails.

from what i understand you only want 1 field at minimum to be present (and valid) for the validation to be ok.
the require_without_all validation should do it:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'avatar' => 'required_without_all:firstName,lastName|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        'firstName'    =>  'required_without_all:avatar,lastName',
        'lastName'  =>  'required_without_all:avatar,firstName'
    ]);
```

(i have not checked your code after validation though)

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.. appreciated.. i just tried and it goes to the white page of death upon submit.. i also tried 'required_without:  and that also does the same. Damn it. It's literally my final piece to fix too, typical!

Comment: just try the validation only (comment out all the below code) and see if it works, then start adding your code.if it works the error is in the logic below

Comment: Thank you very much! commented out and found it was the image coding messing it about.. needed to separate it with if statements too!